# Webcomponent vue not showing

Tags: vue.js, web-component, vue-cli

There is an app that needs to be packaged in a web-component.

**Using the command:**

```
vue-cli-service build --target wc --name my-component 'src/components/*.vue' --inline-vue
```

I'm trying to connect on a third-party site (regular index.html), but the page is empty, there are no errors in the console.

**add:**

```
<my-component></my-component>
<script src='path/to/my-component.js'></script>
```

**vue.config.js:**

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
 module.exports = defineConfig({
 transpileDependencies: true,
 css: {
  extract: false,
  }
 })
```

What did I miss?

Comment: You could check with CSS ``:defined`` if the custom element was actually defined.